# How to remove "X days ago" on WordPress page from Google SERP?

Tags: google, google-search, html, wordpress, search-results

This is a WordPress **page** (not blog post), how do I remove this "X days ago" text from SERP?

I looked for answers on Google and all of them are for blog posts, not pages

[image]

Comment: You cannot remove this.

Comment: I don't think that is correct, closetnoc.   Google doesn't show that date when the "posted on" date isn't displayed on the site.

Comment: Stephen is right, when there is no any date on article or also in sitemap or also in schema then Google don't show the date. My own website is example.

Comment: Things may have changed since I answered a similar ish question quite some time ago. This used to come from the inception date in the index which cannot be controlled. Any new info would be appreciated. I would rather be right than wrong unless being wrong is funny somehow. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Google can pick up date from anywhere.

1. From blog post, like published on.
2. From schema (Published, or Modified Date) if you're using.
3. From sitemap if there is date given.

You can use [some plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/wp-post-date-remover/) to remove date from blog post, but if you're using some sitemap plugin like yoast then they have inbuilt date is given, so google can use that date in search snippet. In short to remove the date, then don't display date anywhere, where googlebot crawl the webpage.

The latest date (Like two days ago or 13 April 2017) helps to increase CTR from search, because most of user like to see fresh result. So I think it's benificial. But if you want to remove that, then please ask specific question on [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) like how to not display date on blog post and second how to remove date from yoast, all in one seo, or Google sitemap plugin. Or Develop own plugin which did not display date on sitemap.